# error in accessing a nested json within a list in a json in python

Tags: python, json, list

I have this sample `json` data that is coming as a response from a `POST` request- `response` is the name of below sample `json` data variable:

```
{
    "statusCode": "OK",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": -199,
            "result": {
                "title": "test1",
                "group": "test_grp2"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": -201,
            "result": {
                "title": "test2",
                "group": "test_grp2"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Now what I want to do is form a `list of list` where each list will have `id`,`title`,and `group` values from above `json` data. Here is what my code looks like:

```
def get_list():
    # code to get the response from POST request

    json_data = json.loads(response.text)
    group_list = []

    if json_data['statusCode'] == 'OK':
        for data in json_data['data']:
            print(data)
            for result_data in data['result']:  
                title = result_data['title']
                group = result_data['group']
            group_list.append([data['id'],title,group])

    return(group_list)
```

When I execute this I get error as `list indices must be int not str` at line `title = result_data['title]`. How can I form the list of list above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data['result']` in your case is a *dictionary*. When you iterate over it using `for result_data in data['result']`, you get the keys - in other words, `result_data` is a string and it does not support string indexing.

Instead, you meant:

```
for data in json_data['data']:
    result_data = data['result']

    title = result_data['title']
    group = result_data['group']
```

Or, alternatively, you can make use of a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
group_list = [(data['id'], data['result']['title'], data['result']['group'])
              for data in json_data['data']]
print(group_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the list of lists directly using a list comprehension:

```
>>> [[d['id'], d['result']['title'], d['result']['group']] for d in json_data['data']]
[[-199, 'test1', 'test_grp2'], [-201, 'test2', 'test_grp2']]
```